# How to extract tags with beautiful soup having data mapping with each other?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

```
<ruling cchwin-doctype="ADMIN-DECISION" node-type="document" normval="20-1ARBP7587"
root="cch-internal-ref" sort-date="20200214"….>
<alias normval="richardvankalker" pub="arb" root="cch-internal-ref"/>
<alias normval="richard_vankalker" pub="arb" root="cch-internal-ref"/>
<heading align="left">Lewis County Rural Electric Cooperative Association and International
Brotherhood of Electrical Workers, Local Union Number 2.</heading>
<ruling-caption>
<ruling-citation-line>RICHARD VAN KALKER, Arbitrator. Selected by the parties. Hearing held 
in Canton, Missouri, May 8, 2019. Post-hearing briefs filed by June 21, 2019. Award issued 
on July 10, 2019.</ruling-citation-line>
```

I am extracting tags through beautiful soup , but i am not able to map the correct data with correct tag.
for example:-
i want normval tag should have the mapping with ruling-citation-line tag, like if make a csv file output should be like:-

```
normval        ruling-citation-line
20-1ARBP7587     RICHARD VAN KALKER, Arbitrator
```

Like normval should have the above ruling-citation value

When i am extracting the data seperately for each tag and then dumping into csv files , i am not able to have the above correct mapped data.
i am really stuck at this.Please help how should i go about this.

Comment: You have quite a few issues here, not the least of which is: how do you get from "richardvankalker" to "RICHARD VAN KALKER"?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting that i am getting by extracting the ruling-citation-line tag and then , cleaning the data obtained and extracting only name from the data , i am not understanding how to map the tags>?

Comment: I got it now. So what I would recommend you do is this: use lxml instead of beautifulsoup, create rows using xpath, add them to a pandas dataframe (I'm sure there's more than one `<ruling>` in CCH :D) and then save to csv or whatever. It's fairly simple to demonstrate it on your sample xml. And please make sure the sample represents the actual xml; for example, each `<ruling>` including its `<ruling-caption>` are probably wrapped inside another tag to separate them from other rulings. Your sample doesn't reflect that.